# How I can show message if the value exists in the table?

Tags: php, laravel

this is my store function in the controller I want to say if the value of coursenum is exit before in my table don't store and show the message to inform the user to rewrite other value

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
$excuse->coursenum  = $request->input('coursenum ');
         if($requests = Student::where ( 'coursenum ', 'LIKE', '%' . coursenum  . '%' )
         {
           return ('the number is exit , write othe value');
         }
 return redirect('/students');
    }
```

Comment: You wan to show message in the view blade?

Comment: yes I want to show the message in the view blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unique` [Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique).

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'coursenum' => Rule::unique('student')->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', 2);
    })
]);
```

Comment: And if I want to make the double check.. I mean if the user Enter the value and existing in my table AND in the same time the stauts_id = 2?

Comment: @shrooq Updated the answer.

Comment: No. I mean if the user enter the value of coursenum the system will check if the value exit and the status_id = 2 will not store and show the message to enter other value. In other story .. if the user enter the value and is an exit in my table but the status is not 2 the system will accept the order.

Comment: yes, the above code will check if the value is unique and has a status of 2. Check the Link that I posted.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Rule' not found

Comment: use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.student' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Student` where `coursenum` = 12345 and (`status_id` = 2))

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel unique validation on your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'coursenum' => 'unique:students'
    ]);
    return redirect('/students');
}
```

then show the error message on the blade

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

You can visit laravel documentation for more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: You can pass custom error message as follows
`
$this->validate(
            $request,
            ['coursenum' => 'unique:students'],
            ['coursenum.unique' => 'custom unique message here']
        );
`